# Compiling sparc code for x86 and arm

Tags: c, arm, sparc

Let's say I've got a collection of source code written for second-generation sparc processors, and some of the C code is architecture-dependent. How can I compile this code for x86 and ARM processors? I initially thought it'd be easy to use GCC and cross compile, but that seems to be too simple. Am I at least on the right track? Thanks!

Comment: Architecture-dependent code, by definition, will need _rewriting_ appropriately for different architectures. Depending on what it does, and how the architectures in question differ, that may or may not be simple.

Comment: I think you need to give examples of *architecture-dependent*.  This could be inline assembler, endian issues, or code generation and timing problems.  There are different tools and techniques to solve each issue.

Answer (score 2):

You can compile it by using compilers that target the required platforms, on whatever host you like. If you're cross-compiling or not doesn't matter.

What matter is that if the code contains non-portable things, you're going to have to fix those manually. No compiler can do that for you.

For instance, if you assume that the code is running on a big-endian architecture, you're going to have to find all such places and fix them (since x86 and, typically, ARM too are both little-endian). Have fun.